# Need dynamic dates in my SQL where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I need to write a (my first) simple stored procedure in SQL Server 2012 that will run on the 1st of every month. The data needs to be for the last 3 full months every time it runs.

I need the `WHERE` clause to be based on a `table.STARTDATE` that falls between the dates of the last 3 months.

So when it runs July 1st, it needs to be:

```
WHERE t.STARTDATE BETWEEN '2018-04-01' AND '2018-06-30'
```

and when it runs on August 1st, it needs to be:

```
WHERE t.STARTDATE BETWEEN '2018-05-01' AND '2018-07-31'
```

and so on.

OK, I just tried this and can't really validate it until the last day of the month. Would this work?

```
BETWEEN DATEADD(m, -3, GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(dd, -1, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 1):

You have it correctly (*assuming time codes do not matter*).

Just as an FYI when doing this sort of thing, you have to remember that you can force dates into the code to test it.

As such:

```
SELECT dateadd(m,-3,'08/01/2018'), dateadd(dd,-1,'08/01/2018')
SELECT dateadd(m,-3,'07/01/2018'), dateadd(dd,-1,'07/01/2018')
```

Which would test it for July 1st and August 1st (your theorectical date)

Comment: You are right, this does work!  I was forgetting that when it runs my -1 will be the first. So I had to hard code using 4-19 instead of 4-1 to validate. I was making it to difficult. Thank you for the guidance!

Answer (score 1):

One way for doing this is using a CTE. This link will be useful to you..

[TSQL loop months in sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30195987/tsql-loop-months-in-sequence)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
where t.STARTDATE >= dateadd(month, -3, datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 
1)) and
      t.STARTDATE < datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1)
```

For reasons why you should not get in the habit of using `between` with dates, I refer you to Aaron Bertrand's blog, [What do between and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)

Answer (score 1):

you can do it by defining dates, here `getdate()` will be your `table.STARTDATE`

```
declare @myStartdate date=dateadd(MM, -3,getdate())
declare @myEnddate date=dateadd(MM, -1,getdate())

SELECT getdate() as today, CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(@myStartdate)-1),@myStartdate),101) AS Date_start_Value,
CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,@myEnddate))),
DATEADD(mm,1,@myEnddate)),101) as date_end_value
```

this will return

```
today                    Date_start_Value   date_end_value

2018-06-20 21:34:07.180  03/01/2018          05/31/2018
```

now you can use above in your where clause

```
WHERE t.STARTDATE BETWEEN 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(@myStartdate)-1),@myStartdate),101) 
AND 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,@myEnddate))),
DATEADD(mm,1,@myEnddate)),101)`
```